# How to solve NullPointer exception in service instantiation using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have two Tests, the first works well, the second fails. It seems that the service is null, but should´t @InjectMocks avoid this situation? I tried @Spy, @Before to setup mock either, but none with success...can someone help me?

the class is above

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ElegibilidadeMultiplaServiceTest {

@Spy
@InjectMocks
private ElegibilidadeMultiplaService elegibilidadeMultiplaService;

@Mock
private MessageFac message;

@Test
public void obterElegibilidadeComSucesso() throws Exception {

    Mockito.doReturn(retornaVerdadeiro()).when(elegibilidadeMultiplaService)
            .executeAndLogSoap(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());

    Map<Long, Boolean> mapa = elegibilidadeMultiplaService.consultaElegibilidadeListaEC(getListaEcs());

    assertFalse(mapa.isEmpty());

}

@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void deveLancarExcecaoGenerica() throws Exception {

    Mockito.doThrow(Exception.class).when(elegibilidadeMultiplaService)
            .executeAndLogSoap(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());

    elegibilidadeMultiplaService.consultaElegibilidadeListaEC(getListaEcs());

}

private List<Long> getListaEcs() {

    List<Long> numerosEC = new ArrayList<>();

    add objects to list

    return numerosEC;
}

private VerificarClienteExistenteResponseType retornaVerdadeiro() {

    VerificarClienteExistenteResponseType resp = new VerificarClienteExistenteResponseType();
    resp.setIndicadorClienteExistente(Boolean.TRUE);

    return resp;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please 1) show entire stack trace 2) show service under test

Comment: That is the trace already

Comment: I don´t have the class here right now, but it extends another class that contains executeAndSoap method. But the truth is that I don´t have any idea why elegibilidadeMultiplaService is null at the time that calls  "elegibilidadeMultiplaService.consultaElegibilidadeListaEC(getListaEcs());" on the second test

Comment: as the first test runs, it seels highly unlikely that `elegibilidadeMultiplaService` is `null` in the second test.
Also, the stack trace provided does not show `NullPointerExceptions`. Instead it appears as if an error without a message is thrown which appears to be exactly what you are coding. Try changing `doThrow(Exception.class)` to `doThrow(new Exception("message"))` and see if that changes anything

Comment: `ElegibilidadeMultiplaService` is the class under test right? Why is it a `@Spy`?

Comment: Stefan Helmerichs, you were right, that solved the question. Thanks a lot. I shouldn´t expect an Exception.class, actually just let the method works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was doing something wrong considering my method implementation. This should be the test

```
    @Test
public void deveFalharAoMontarMapa() throws Exception {

    Mockito.doThrow(Exception.class)
            .when(elegibilidadeMultiplaService)
            .executeAndLogSoap(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());

    Map<Long, Boolean> mapa = elegibilidadeMultiplaService.consultaElegibilidadeListaEC(getListaEcs());

    assertTrue(mapa.isEmpty());
}
```

Thanks to Stefan Helmerichs I could see what was wrong. The exception is not exactly the return I expected from the method, just part of it.